# Why is this true? $\forall a\in(1,\infty), B\in(0,\infty), x\in(0,\infty) : a^x\geq \left(\frac{ex\ln(a)}{B}\right)^{B}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, taylor-expansion, puzzle, means

I know 
$$\forall a\in(1,\infty), B\in(0,\infty), x\in(0,\infty)$$
$$a^x\geq \left(\frac{ex\ln(a)}{B}\right)^{B}$$
can be proved using AM-GM. Is there a simple way to show the inequality holds in all those cases?
This comparison seems to me to not be equal anywhere so far as I have noticed, so if you replace $e$ with a larger number such that the comparison is equal, what is the maximum number to replace $e$?

Comment: Since $x \ln(a) = a^x$ this can be simplified to $k \ge \left(\frac{e \ln(k)}{B}\right)^B$ for $k>1$, $B>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a^x = k$ and treat the right-hand side as a function $f(B) = \left(\frac{e \ln(k)}{B}\right)^B$. Then $$\lim_{B \to 0} f(B) = 1 \text{ and }\lim_{B\to\infty} f(B) = 0$$ and $$f'(B) = e^B \left(\frac{\ln (k)}{B}\right)^B \ln\left(\frac{\ln (k)}{B}\right).$$ So the only critical point is at $B=\ln(k)$. One can check that the second derivative is negative and so it is a local maximum. Then note that $f(\ln(k)) = k$.

Comment: Your limits should read
$$\lim_{B \to 0} f(B) = 1$$
and
$$\lim_{B\to\infty} f(B) = 0$$
. Also, the critical point, $B=\ln(k)$, is the global maximum of $f(B)$, not the local minimum.

Comment: So true. This is what happens in the haste of trying to get out of the office at the end of the day. Corrected now, though the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^x\geq \left(\frac{ex\ln(a)}{B}\right)^{B}
\\
\iff
x\ln a\geq B\ln \left(\frac{ex\ln a}{B}\right)
\iff
\frac{x\ln a}{B} \geq \ln \left(e\frac{x\ln a}{B}\right)
= 1 + \ln\left(\frac{x\ln a}{B}\right)
$$

Now it is the well known inequality
$$
\ln(1+u)\le u
$$with
$$
u = \frac{x\ln a}{B} - 1
$$

There is equality iff
$$
u = 0 \iff x\ln a = B
$$

Answer (score 0):

The way I proved [here](http://pepticskeptic.blogspot.com/2014/10/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean_7.html) this inequality is by using the Weighted Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean Inequality using a Taylor series as the weights for another Taylor series.
The method used was outlines [here](http://pepticskeptic.blogspot.com/2014/10/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean.html).